# wso2 esb enrich text in xml

Tags: xml, xpath, wso2-esb

I'm trying to enrich the text of an XML-Node with WSO2 ESB Version 4.9.0.

Simple XML:

```
<enrich>
    <source type="inline">
        <query><where><order.id>0</order.id></where></query>
    </source>
    <target type="body" />
</enrich>
```

Enrich:

```
<enrich>
    <source type="property" property="uri.var.processId" />
    <target action="replace" type="body" xpath="//order.id/text()" />
</enrich>
```

But the output looks like this:

```
<query xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"><where><order.id>0</order.id></where>SOHBSS-000002</query>
```

When I was expecting this:

```
<query xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"><where><order.id>SOHBSS-000002</order.id></where></query>
```

When I even more simplify the given XML to `<order.id>0</order.id>` the same enrich mediator from above, gives the correct `<order.id xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">SOHBSS-000002</order.id>` output.

Is the xpath wrong? Or am I using the enrich mediator for something that it's not made for?

Because the XML is simple, I'm trying to not us XSLT to do the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second enrich, try to replace target type from body to custom :

```
<enrich>
    <source type="property" property="uri.var.processId" />
    <target action="replace" type="custom" xpath="//order.id/text()" />
</enrich>
```

Comment: I'm getting following error, when I use type="custom": EnrichMediator Invalid Target object to be enrich
(I'm not doing anything else between those two enrich mediators, so I don't know why that would end in an error)

Comment: I had to additionaly set an empty Namespace for the XML: <query xmlns=""> - now it's working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had some tough time trying to do an xpath on tags with namespaces, so here it is (thanks Lesrac for yor comments about xmlns)

```
<enrich>
    <source type="inline">
        <query namespace="http://www.fadata.bg/Insurance_Messages/v3.0/xml/">
          <where><order.id>0</order.id></where></query>
    </source>
    <target type="body" />
</enrich>
<enrich>
    <source type="property" property="uri.var.processId" />
    <target action="replace" type="custom" xpath="//fadata:order.id/text()"
       xmlns:fadata="http://www.fadata.bg/Insurance_Messages/v3.0/xml/"/>
</enrich>
```